# In pandas, how can I reset index without adding a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
In [37]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]])

In [38]: df2 = pd.concat([df, df])

In [39]: df2.reset_index()
Out[39]: 
   index  0  1  2  3
0      0  1  2  3  4
1      1  2  3  4  5
2      2  3  4  5  6
3      0  1  2  3  4
4      1  2  3  4  5
5      2  3  4  5  6
```

How can I `reset_index` without adding a new column `index`?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can use the `drop=True` option in `reset_index()`. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Answer (score 5):

An often encountered issue is that `reset_index()` returns a copy, so it will have to be assigned to another variable (or itself) to modify the dataframe. You can also use the `inplace=` parameter to remove the old indexes in-place.

```py
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
# or
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df
```

[image: res]

---

Keep in mind that many pandas functions/methods that remove rows or otherwise change index (e.g. `dropna`, `drop_duplicates`, `pd.concat` etc.) have `ignore_index` parameter which when set to True resets the index as part of the function call. For example, in the example used in the OP, simply passing `ignore_index=True` avoids the need to reset the index in the first place.

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True)  # <--- no need for `reset_index()`
```