# 1 column gets added after resetting index in Pandas

Tags: indexing, pandas, reset

How do I reset index of a dataframe without getting an extra column?
I tried answer given here [In pandas, how can I reset index without adding a new column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167829/in-pandas-how-can-i-reset-index-without-adding-a-new-column) but it drops the original index. I would like the original index to remain in the df.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,5]],columns=['a','b'],index=[12,13])
>>> df
    a  b
12  1  2
13  3  5
>>> df.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> df
   index  a  b
0     12  1  2
1     13  3  5

>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,5]],columns=['a','b'],index=[12,13])
>>> df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  5
```

Comment: Sorry what are you wanting, it's unclear why you'd reset the index but not want the index to start from 0 again?

Comment: @Edchum Sorry, I am using Pandas only for a month. I am using multi column index/multi-index. I need to filter out some rows based on value of one of these index columns. Which I think Pandas doesnt allow on a index column. So I am using reset and setting it back again. I need these index values again for calulations. My worry is reset is adding columns, making datasize bigger.

Comment: No that is allowed but your sample data is not representative of your real problem, please post representative input data, code and desired output

Comment: ok , I will take out sample code and data to post here by tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want. You appear to be saying that you want a new index, keep the old index, but don't keep the old index as a new column. I am not sure what that means.

if you just want a new index without an extra column in the data frame ...

```
df.index = range(len(df))
```

If you just want to pop the current index into the data frame, but also keep the current index unchanged ...

```
df['index'] = df.index
```

If you want to put the old index into the data frame and create a new index, but you have a strong moral objection to using pandas.DataFrame.reset_index(), then you can try the following ...

```
df['old_index'] = df.index
df.index = range(len(df))
```